# MS Access: Importing Table with keeping the existing record

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to make a table in my access which the records are imported daily to this. In my access I am planning to add another column to write some notes. I would like to know whats the best way to import "the new records" while keeping the existing ones the same. My importing table looks like this:

```
SN     Unit      Date      
26      71       19/08/2015
25      68       20/08/2015
01      34       20/08/2015
..      ..        .......
```

So what I am planning to do is to import the record of the last 30 days each day and Edit some of them by adding another column of Notes next to the Date (Table above).

So what I want is basically adding all the records except those ones which are similar (lets say with the same Unique SN, in this case I want to keep the existing ones).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you will have to do programmatically.

You can import all the data from mysql and then make a query ... into table mixing your existing data and your new data, but this will be very time-consuming, because you will end importing data that will be discarded after all.

A better way will be importing only what you really need.